# MVC Model Structure - Navigation Properties - Reuse of the same table for different properties

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a model called Course and a model called Resources.  The Resources are 'people'. I have several Resources that are part of the Course but that serve in different capacities.  For instance, I have a property in Course that is of type Resource called PortfolioLeadId.  I also have a property that is of type Resource that is called EditorId.  There's different Resources that are associated with a Course based on the Resource Type.  I attempted to create the below Model with navigation properties. For my Create and Edit views, I generate drop down/select lists from the Resource table where I save the ID's of the selected Resource to the associated Resource Type in the Course.  e.g. PortfolioLeadId and EditorId.  However, when I try to create a DisplayFor in the Details View, the navigation properties of the Portfolio Lead and Editor do not work.  What I mean by this is that if I do @Html.DisplayFor(m=>m.PortfolioLead.Name) for example, it returns null!?

What do I need to change in order to navigate?

```
 public class Course
{
    public int CourseId { get; set; }
    public int? PortfolioLeadId { get; set; }
    public int? EditorId { get; set; }
   ...lots of other properties

   //navigation properties
   public virtual Resource PortfolioLead { get; set; }
   public virtual Resource Editor { get; set; }
}

//Controller
    public ActionResult Details(int? id)
    {
        ViewBag.Courses = "active";
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Course course = db.Course.Find(id);
        if (course == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

        return View(course);
    }


//Fields removed for brevity
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Courses] (
[CourseId]                      INT             IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[EditorId]                      INT             NULL,
[Editor_ResourceId]             INT             NULL,
[PortfolioLeadId]               INT             NULL,
[PortfolioLead_ResourceId]      INT             NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Courses] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([CourseId] ASC),
CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Courses_dbo.Resources_PortfolioLead_ResourceId] FOREIGN    KEY ([PortfolioLead_ResourceId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Resources] ([ResourceId]),
CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Courses_dbo.Resources_Editor_ResourceId] FOREIGN KEY ([Editor_ResourceId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Resources] ([ResourceId])

);


GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Editor_ResourceId]
ON [dbo].[Courses]([Editor_ResourceId] ASC);

GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_PortfolioLead_ResourceId]
ON [dbo].[Courses]([PortfolioLead_ResourceId] ASC);
```

Comment: By "Don't work" you mean?

Comment: Can you show the controller code that populates the view's model?  The Entities look like they are setup correctly, I'm guessing the problem is how they are being loaded.

Comment: Its just the standard 'Details' setup.  Updated above.

Comment: See if the `Resource` properties are getting bound when you fetch the `course`.

Comment: The Id's are stored in the course object that is fetched but the Resource properties are null, which is the issue.  I just don't know why if the Course Entity is setup correctly...

Comment: `db` is your database context?  If so, try changing it to `db.Course.Include(c=>c.PortfolioLead).Include(c=>c.Editor).Find(id);`

Comment: @Bradley.  Yes db is the database context.  No dice on the includes  :(

Comment: Have you verified in the database that there are actually associated entities linked to the `Course`?

Comment: Added schema above.  I'm using Code First as I go to build out the db. Interesting that EF created [EditorId]  and {Editor_ResourceId]?

Comment: Is there some sort of Attribute tag that I need over the EditorId field to map it to the navigation property so that EF doesn't generate a new id automatically?